# ANDROID_HOME not found on Mac OS x when running build job with Bamboo

Tags: android, gradle, bamboo, android-sdk-2.3

I'm running android on a Bamboo server hosted on a Mac OS (Yosemite). I have set the path to android_sdk, both in bash_profile and in /etc/path. Checking that:

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
> /Applications/Android/sdk
```

But when running the build I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

My problem is that this will be run from different type of machines, a linux and a MAC OS, so the path might vary. So defining a path in as an Environmental variable is not an alternative, since it might vary for the different operating system. I don't want to create separate builds for different machines.

I also haven't found any alternativ to set the variable as a capability for the bamboo agent, maybe there is?

Any suggestions how to solve this? Can I specify it in gradle somehow? Checking in local.properties is not an alternative.

Comment: How to setup NDK in Bamboo?

Answer (score 1):

In Creation of task for the plan, just provide the android sdk location (on CI server) in Environment variables. Check the screen shot attached, in my case it was placed at : "ANDROID_HOME="/Users/{your user}/Library/Android/sdk[image]"

Comment: This worked for me: ANDROID_HOME=/Library/AndroidSDK/android-sdk-macosx, no " needed

Comment: I can't see how this can work if the path varies on different agent machines with different OS´s?

Answer (score 0):

I have heard before that if the problem has to do with Gradle, configuring the ANDROID_HOME maybe won't work. Here is a solution that is usually working for projects on Android Studio...

In your project's directory add a file named `local.properties.` Then add the following line in there:

`sdk.dir=/Applications/Android/sdk`

This file is usually created automatically generated by Android Studio. It also has the following comments in it:

> This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
>
> Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
>
> This file should *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
>   as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
>
> Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
>   For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
>   header note.

Comment: I can't see how this can work if the path varies on different agent machines with different OS´s?